# Docker Build a GitHub Repository and Push to DockerHub

Tags: git, docker, build

I've got a GitHub repo which has a Dockerfile in the project root. I want to build the repository, but am experiencing errors.

Command run (The `Dockerfile` is located in the repository root, in the `main` branch)

```sh
$ docker build https://github.com/$RepoOwner/$RepositoryName.git#main:.
$ docker build https://github.com/$RepoOwner/$RepositoryName.git#main:
```

Both yield the following error:

```
unable to prepare context: unable to 'git clone' to temporary context directory: error initializing submodules: usage: git submodule [--quiet] add [-b <branch>] [-f|--force] [--name <name>] [--reference <repository>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] status [--cached] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] init [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] deinit [-f|--force] [--] <path>...
   or: git submodule [--quiet] update [--init] [--remote] [-N|--no-fetch] [-f|--force] [--rebase] [--reference <repository>] [--merge] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] summary [--cached|--files] [--summary-limit <n>] [commit] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] foreach [--recursive] <command>
   or: git submodule [--quiet] sync [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
: exit status 1
```

Comment: Something in the docker setup is invoking `git submodule` incorrectly. Without more information, that's all I can say. (Note: this isn't a Linux kernel / API issue and isn't a GItHub issue, so I snipped those two tags.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by cloning the Git repository and then running docker build on it.